# How to take average of value taken twice a minute from MySQL

Tags: mysql, average

Hello my mysql table looks like this:

```
select 
distinct(TimeStamp) , 
TP_bmp183 as "t:emperature_;_p:reassure" 
from 
gadbdfm 
where 
TimeStamp 
BETWEEN  '2016-12-10 08:10%' AND '2016-12-10 08:15%' ;
    +----------------------------+----------------------------+
    | TimeStamp                  | t:emperature_;_p:reassure  |
    +----------------------------+----------------------------+
    | 2016-12-10 08:10:15.087235 | t: -0.700000;p: 998.470000 |
    | 2016-12-10 08:10:52.553992 | t: -0.500000;p: 998.460000 |
    | 2016-12-10 08:11:44.747368 | t: 0.100000;p: 998.520000  |
    | 2016-12-10 08:12:14.647513 | t: 0.200000;p: 998.450000  |
    | 2016-12-10 08:12:47.107094 | t: 0.200000;p: 998.410000  |
    | 2016-12-10 08:13:14.439774 | t: 0.200000;p: 998.430000  |
    | 2016-12-10 08:13:44.367472 | t: 0.000000;p: 998.440000  |
    | 2016-12-10 08:14:14.254476 | t: -0.300000;p: 998.550000 |
    | 2016-12-10 08:14:44.171212 | t: -0.600000;p: 998.420000 |
    +----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

So as it can be seen I have like two values taken 
twice a minute. I really need to have like one value for a minute entry **2016-12-10 08:10** which means **t: -0.600000;p: 998.465000**.

- temperature: -0.70000 and -0.500000 is -**0.60000**
- preassure: 998.470000 and 998.460000 is **998.465000**

Comment: Your `TP_bmp183` format is a mess. Can't you use 2 normal columns?

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in my earlier answer.  Please see it updated below.  (BTW, you can also accept my answer to make it "definitive")

Comment: Distinct is NOT a function. The parentheses you have used in the query above are simply ignored. `select distinct` is a row operation, it considers the entire row content to decide if each row is unique.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    date_format(TimeStamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') timeStampRoundedToMinute
    , concat(TP_bmp183) as debugPrint 
    , avg(substring_index(substring_index(TP_bmp183, ';', 1),  ':', -1)) avgTemp
    , avg(substring_index(substring_index(TP_bmp183, ';', -1), ':', -1)) avgPressure
from 
    gadbdfm 
where 
    TimeStamp BETWEEN  '2016-12-10 08:10%' AND '2016-12-10 08:15%' 
group by date_format(TimeStamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i');
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitive answer:

Thanks @leeyuiwah

```
select 
    date_format(TimeStamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as timeStampRoundedToMinute
    , concat(TP_bmp183) as "debug use -- t:emperature_;_p:reassure" 
    , avg(substring_index(substring_index(TP_bmp183, ';', 1),  ':', -1))as avgTemp
    , avg(substring_index(substring_index(TP_bmp183, ';', -1), ':', -1))as avgPressure
from 
    gadbdfm
where
    TimeStamp
BETWEEN  '2016-12-10 08:10%' AND '2016-12-10 08:15%'
group by date_format(TimeStamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i');
```